# How many partitions in lan computer

Tags: networking, lan, cmd.exe

I need a way perhaps CMD in windows to discover names of paritions in a LAN computer (something like DIR) to display his > my computer drives

I already have admin account that i can login and already could access c$ and d$ but i need to know if there is other drives there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are trying to get the details of the remote machine. Use psexec.exe (Microsoft PStools) to obtain partition details of the remote machine. Download the psexec.exe tool in your local machine and open a command prompt, then navigate to the psexec.exe path and run the below command:

```
PsExec.exe \\remotemachine -u username -p password wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,drivetype,providername,volumename
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the username and password i have belong to domain, when i tried it says (
PsExec could not start wmic on ncexx:
The user name or password is incorrect. )

Comment: Did you try the domain username as like "domainname\username". PsExec.exe \\remotemachine -u domainname\username -p password wmic logicaldisk get caption,description,drivetype,providername,volumename

Answer (score 1):

From powershell run this command under your admin account:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_DiskPartition -ComputerName OTHERCOMPUTER
```

Comment: I need to that from another computer

Comment: Edited it to let you do it remotely

Comment: Just anywhere in a powershell prompt

Comment: OK, I did it, i need to know the name of the parition like C, D, E

Comment: Also i need to put username and password to access remotely

Comment: Type this at a powershell prompt: Get-help Get-WMIObject -detail